# Behavior of the all target in Makefile

Tags: build, makefile

I have the following makefile :

```
DESTFILES = build/test1 build/toto2

build/test1: test1
    cp $< $@

build/toto2: toto2
    cp $< $@

all:    build/test1 build/toto2
```

The directory in which the Makefile resides contains the `build` subdirectory and the `test1`, `toto2` empty files.

The aim is to copy the files to the build subdirectory (a la `make install`).

When I do a `make all` command, the files are copied appropriately in `build`.
But when I do just `make` only the first target of `all`, `test1` is triggered and so only the first file is copied.

I am very suprised at this behavior. Can anyone enlighten me about this ?

This is with GNU Make 4.1 on Archlinux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GNU make, the default goal (the target that is done when you just type `make`) is the first one which name does not start with '.'. `all` is just a name, GNU make does not do anything special with it. If you want it to be the default, put it in first position or use the special `.DEFAULT_GOAL`variable:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` [Special Variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables) as well. Which lets you define the default target regardless of location.

Comment: Good point. I updated my answer and also mentioned that target names starting with '.' are not considered when defining the default goal. Thanks.